# IIS not recognizing binding to .academy domain

Tags: iis, binding, iis-8, windows-server

I am running a new ASP web application for a new project which I am to host on my Windows server along with a dozen other already active (and functioning) applications.

The new project requires an unusual domain ending in `.academy`, which has proven to give me issues. I have already successfully mapped the running application to one of my other domains, but when attempting to bind to the `.academy` domain, hits to the address fall through to the standard IIS landing page.

- **Note that requests do actually hit my server**

My experience is mainly within code, and not within server configuration so the solution to this might be trivial. However, this has proven to have wasted many working hours already.